# Is there a mothod to shift all the vowels present in string to the beginning

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write a program that receives a string and shifts all the vowels present in it to the beginning.

I have tried sorting the vowels one by one and removing them on the go and saving the two strings separately,then at the end i joined it

```
s = "You love Python!"
vowels = "aeiou"
s1= ""
for l in range(0,len(s)):
    if s[l] in vowels:
        s1 = s1+s[l]
        s2 = s.replace(s[l],"")

print(s1+s2)
```

OUTPUT :

```
ouoeoYu lve Pythn!
```

But in output "e" in second word is not sorted. What is the error?

Answer (score 3):

**Problem:**

The reason your code does not quite work is because you sometimes use `s` and sometimes `s2`. `s.replace(s[l],"")` does nothing to `s` - so every time you use it, `s2` gets to be `s` with one vowel replaced in it - the others vowels are taken as isfor `s`.

The last vowel replaced is `o` - so `s2` becomes:  `Yu lve Pythn!` - `u` and `e` are still in it.

**Your code fixed:**

```
s = "You love Python!"
vowels = "aeiou"
s1 = ""
for c in  s:
    if c in vowels:
        s1 = s1+c                  # produces new string every time
        s = s.replace(c,"")        # produces new string every time

print(s1+s) # ouoeoY lv Pythn!
```

---

**Optimizations:**

Do not iterate by index, iterate over the characters of a string directly. If you collect things from strings, avoid producing more strings, use a list instead. Strings are immuteable, every time you modify one it is constructed new.

*Suboptimal:*
You can use list comprehensions to get the chars into two lists, combine both lists and join them back into a string:

```
s = "You love Python!"

s1 = [x for x in s if x.lower() in "aeiou"] # gets vowels, order and capitalization is kept
s2 = [x for x in s if x.lower() not in "aeiou"]  # gets all other characters

s3 = ''.join(s1+s2)  # adds lists back together and makes it a continious string

print(s1)
print(s2)
print(s3)
```

Output:

```
['o', 'u', 'o', 'e', 'o']
['Y', ' ', 'l', 'v', ' ', 'P', 'y', 't', 'h', 'n', '!']
ouoeoY lv Pythn!
```

**Disadvantage:** you have to go over the whole string twice. A simple for loop can do it in one pass:

```
s = "You love Python!"

s1=[]
s2=[]
for c in s:
    if c in "aeiou":
        s1.append(c)
    else:
        s2.append(c)

s3 = ''.join(s1+s2)
print(s1)
print(s2)
print(s3)
```

Output is the same.

---

Doku:

- [python list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
- [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)
- [str.join( iterable )](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "You love Python"
vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU'
v = ""
c = ""
for i in s:
    if i in vowels:
        v = v+i
    else:
        c= c+i
        
final_string = v+c
print(final_string)
```

Comment: Except for the capital letters, this is exactly the same code as in the other answer. Just without any explanation. And note, that the `vowels` were given by the asker.

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of the code?